# Embedded youtube videos viewing with iOS 6 - links after iframe not clickable

Tags: html, iframe, ios6, youtube

On my iPad and iPhone both running iOS 6.1.3, I cannot view links that are placed below an embedded youtube video. Here's an example:

```
<a href="http://xenforo.com/community/">Xenforo</a>

<br /><br />

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dCyyNxHmDqg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<br /><br />

<a href="http://xenforo.com/community/">Xenforo</a>
```

You will be able to click the link above the embedded youtube video, but not the one below it. If you start the video the link below the video can be clicked.

Comment: I had the same issue... Do you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems youtube iframes has some extra content which is blocking yout content after iframe. Here is some workaround that helps me to solve this problem(using Jquery. Add this to your window's load event. Actually, you can check for iPhone device before this and apply this code only ofr iPhone devices.

```
$('iframe').each(function () {
     $(this).css({
         'height': this.height - 1
     });
});
```

I am working now to find more clean solution, if I have anything I will update my answer :)

Comment: Hi Chuck, thank you for the code. I tried it and the link below the video now works, however the youtube video cannot be played.

Comment: Here's a discussion on Google Groups about this issue: 

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/Whgd0XmzJxg

Comment: Yeah, it seems like youtube bug. However, in my situation this code works and youtube video have played normally.